# Unable to handle a window event in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I´m developing a WPF desktop application in C# VS 2019 with .net5.0.
I catch the window StateChange event. The event data has type EventArgs, which is just a base class with no usefull info about the event. I want to use cast to ViewStateChangedEventArgs. This class is located in namespace System.Activities.Presentation.View, but this namespace is not included in VS 2019/.net5.0.
My first question is: have I selected the right subclass for event data ?
The namespace is located in System.Activities.Presentation.dll which is a part of .net4.x and resides under x86 components, outside VS. In VS 2019 WPF it is not possible to add a reference (or whatever this component could be) from outside VS, you just cannot freely browse the PC.
How can I add and use this dll in my VS 2019/.net5.0 project ?

Comment: [`Window.StateChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.statechanged?view=net-5.0) is an `EventHandler` that takes an `EventArgs` argument. What makes you think you could cast that to a different type? Use the `WindowState` property in the handler method.

Comment: I've seen many similar threads with solutions that didn't work for me. E.g. switching to .net 4.8 cannot solve this problem. Also, instructions how to add a reference to the project couldn't be followed because they are only applicable to a particular VS version, .net version, and the project type, which is WPF C# desktop. So, if you think you have a solution, please verify that it works (add #using  System.Activities.Presentation.View;) in this environment or recommend another EventArgs subclass.

Comment: You haven't understood what I was saying. It is not possible to use ViewStateChangedEventArgs with the StateChanged event.

Comment: Hi, Clemens. You're right. I'll try this way, thank you. There are EventArgs classes that contain old value and new value for a property, and I was convinced my event handler must use something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.statechanged?view=net-5.0), the `StateChange` is of type `EventHandler`, i.e. it does not contain any meaningful data. And as far as I can tell, the actual argument is just an `EventArgs` *not* `ViewStateChangedEventArgs`. I'm not sure why you think you could cast it to a `ViewStateChangedEventArgs`, but that is probably not the way to do it.

Instead just check the `WindowState` property. If you need the old state you can save this to a field in the constructor, and update it whenever `StateChange` is raised.

Comment: This is of course a correct solution. Clemens suggested it too above. How do I mark this question as answered ?

Comment: @Kalle Svensson If the answer solves the problem you should mark it as accepted. See [How to accept and close a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355769/how-to-accept-and-close-a-question)

Comment: My question has been locked because it lacks coding details and desired behavior, and I was urged to correct these flaws. However, two readers have already proposed a good solution, so there is neither need to improve the question nor to obtain more answers.